# Android/Linux: Delete multiple files containing the @, except for 2 files

Tags: android, special-characters

I'm trying to delete with Terminal Emulator or Termux files located in /data/dalvik-cache/arm. I want to delete all files except for 2 of them:
"system@framework@boot.art" and "system@framework@boot.oat". 
The problem is with the special character "@" found 2 times in the name of the files.

My goal is to write a very rudimentary script for bash, in which I just mount the system, delete everything except those 2, unmount and reboot.
Could someone please help me? I'm rather new to all of this. I've searched many websites, man-pages without any luck mixing the removal of multiple file containing special characters and in the same time excluding some.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
#/system/bin/sh
mount -o rw,remount,rw /system
cd /data/dalvik-cache/arm
shopt -s extglob
rm -v !("system@framework@boot.art"|"system@framework@boot.oat")        --> Syntax error
mount -o ro,remount,ro /system
reboot
```

As indicated, the `rm` command (with the extended wildcard)
gets a "Syntax error".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The first line of your script is a comment. 
   If you mean for it to be a “she-bang”, it must begin with `#!`
   (you left out the `!`).
2. … and then it might work better if you say `#!/system/bin/bash`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I wrote the script in a hurry and must have forgotten about the !. I used the bash provided by Termux and it worked! Thanks again!